# OAuth gem not signing requests

Tags: ruby, oauth

I'm using the ruby gem for OAuth (http://oauth.rubyforge.org/) and I can't get it to create the authorization header for the provider I'm attempting to hit.

Here is my code:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(auth[:consumer_key], auth[:consumer_secret], {
  :site   => 'http://api.rdio.com',
  :scheme => :header
})

access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer)

ap access_token.post('/1', :method => 'search', :query => 'Robert', :types => 'User')
```

When the requests happens, The header is not present in the call.

```
#<Net::HTTP::Post:0x7fbf149e91e0
    @body_data = nil,
    @header = {
                "accept" => [
            [0] "*/*"
        ],
            "user-agent" => [
            [0] "Ruby"
        ],
        "content-length" => [
            [0] "0"
        ],
          "content-type" => [
            [0] "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
    },
```

The header I'm referring to is the one that looks like this:

```
OAuth oauth_nonce=\"225579211881198842005988698334675835446\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_token=\"token_411a7f\", oauth_timestamp=\"1199645624\", oauth_consumer_key=\"consumer_key_86cad9\", oauth_signature=\"1oO2izFav1GP4kEH2EskwXkCRFg%3D\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to do 2-legged oauth. See if this code works for you.

***Edit: Updated Code Sample***

```
gem 'oauth'
require 'oauth'
require 'net/http'

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new('ENTER_KEY', 'ENTER_SECRET', {        
                                :site   => 'http://api.rdio.com',        
                                :scheme => :header        
}) 

resp = consumer.request(:post, '/1/search', nil, {}, 'method=search&query=Robert&types=User', { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
puts resp.code + "\r\n"
puts resp.body
```

***Edit: Added captured http stream***

```
POST /1/search HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
User-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.5
Content-Length: 37
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="REDACTED_KEY", oauth_nonce="dwp8m2TGPHQNx3A7imLi7OkAULL7c0IWbTKefPXCsAY", oauth_signature="LxDZn6UNFLY%2FaXItu6MPK5a11js%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1330193449", oauth_version="1.0"
Connection: close
Host: api.rdio.com

method=search&query=Robert&types=UserHTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Mashery-Responder: mashery-web1.LAX
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
Content-Language: en
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Version: 11.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 25 Feb 2012 18:10:50 GMT
Server: Mashery Proxy
Content-Length: 2763
Connection: close

{"status": "ok", "result": {"person_count": 9603, "track_count": 93409, "number_results": 200, "playlist_count": 205, "results": ***TRUNCATED RESULTS FOR BREVITY***
```

Comment: Negative:
    header = {
          "content-type" => [
            [0] "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
                "accept" => [
            [0] "*/*"
        ],
            "user-agent" => [
            [0] "Ruby"
        ],
        "content-length" => [
            [0] "37"
        ]
    },

Comment: I have updated the answer with confirmed working code example and http stream. I am running ruby 1.9.3 and the oauth gem v0.4.5