# Undefined method `OAuth' when making HTTP request to Twitter api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, httparty

I'm getting the following OAuth error when trying to make a request to the Twitter streaming api:

> "#NoMethodError: undefined method `OAuth' for #TwitterMoment:0x007fa081d821f0"

```
def query
 authorisation_header = OAuth oauth_consumer_key=ENV["oauth_consumer_key"], oauth_nonce=ENV["oauth_nonce"], oauth_signature=ENV["oauth_signature"], oauth_signature_method=ENV["oauth_signature_method"], oauth_timestamp=ENV["oauth_timestamp"], oauth_token=ENV["oauth_token"], oauth_version=ENV["oauth_version"]
 response = HTTParty.get("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-#{@bounds}", headers: {"Authorization" => authorisation_header})
end
```

OAuth is included in my gemfile.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated! This is my first Stack Overflow question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `OAuth` here as a function/method, but that method doesn't exist. There's no `def OAuth(...)` anywhere in the `oauth` gem, so it explodes and gives you that NoMethodError.

Judging from the [Header example at the bottom of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435502/oauth-gem-not-signing-requests), I think you've confused the header string for Ruby code.

Instead, you either need to make the string yourself (a bit annoying to do safely), or use [the OAuth gem's](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby) methods (API) to do so.

Here's [an example from the OAuth github repo](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/blob/master/examples/yql.rb#L35-L44):

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
  options[:consumer_key],
  options[:consumer_secret],
  :site => "http://query.yahooapis.com"
)

access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer)

response = access_token.request(
  :get,
  "/v1/yql?q=#{OAuth::Helper.escape(query)}&format=json"
)
rsp = JSON.parse(response.body)
pp rsp
```

This example may work for you (I'm not able to test it locally here, sorry):

```
def query
  consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
    ENV["oauth_consumer_key"],
    ENV["oauth_consumer_token"],
    site: "https://stream.twitter.com"
  )
  access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer)

  response = access_token.request(
    :get,
    "/1.1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-#{OAuth::Helper.escape(@bounds)}"
  )
  response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  pp response  # Just a bit of debug printing for the moment; remove this later.
  response
end
```

**An addendum:**

Usually I might have directed you to use an existing Twitter client gem, such as https://github.com/sferik/twitter, but in this case it looks like they haven't implemented the Moments API yet.

Comment: Once I read your addendum I realised I already had what I needed! 

I have this Twitter.rb file:

    $twitter = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
     config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
     config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
     config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
     config.access_token_secret =        ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
    end

Query now this:

    `$twitter.filter(locations: @bounds) do |object| puts object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet) end`

and it seems to work!

Comment: The only problem is I'm now wondering if the streaming API might not be what I'm after. I'm trying to capture all tweets from a geographical location at a particular time. Tweets with images in particular. 

Originally I was using the search api, like this ...


    $twitter
      .search("e since:#{from_date} until:#{to_date}",
              geocode: "#{lat},#{long},10km",
              lang: "en",
              count: 100,
              filter: "images"
              )

... but it wasn't returning many results! Even without the images filter it would only return 10 or 20 tweets.

Comment: I read that the search api isn't exhaustive. It only returns a sample of the most recent or popular tweets. And that the streaming api is better for this.

Comment: I'm out of my depth with the specifics of the Twitter API, sorry; I haven't done a Twitter integration since 2009. D:

Comment: @amesimmons That's correct, search is based on relevance (internal Twitter API algorithm), rather than completeness: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search